# Use HWND (or something similar) as Node Image in Virtual Stringtree

Tags: windows, delphi, icons, window-handles

Is it possible to display an Icon obtained from an external Handle, as the Image of my Node in Virtual Stringtree? The Node's Data contains the HWND.

Comment: A `HWND` is a *window* handle. A window is not an icon. An *icon* handle is called a `HICON`. To get the icon of a window, that is, to get the `HICON` of the `HWND`, send the [`WM_GETICON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632625(VS.85).aspx) message to the window.

Comment: @Andreas, I think Jeff wants to get the icon belonging to the window that he's got a HWND for.

Comment: @Johan: Yes, and that's why I told him to use `WM_GETICON`!

Comment: @Andreas I know that I should use the function - my question is: How do I make the image appear in my VirtualStringtree? ;)

Comment: I have never used that control, so Rob Kennedy or some other expert will help you out on this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `ImageList` assigned to your VT's `Images` property and `OnGetImageIndex` event.
Here's how to fill the image list using [WM_GETICON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632625%28VS.85%29.aspx).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var IconHandle: HIcon;

begin
  IconHandle := SendMessage(123456, WM_GETICON, ICON_SMALL2, 0);
  ImageList_AddIcon(ImageList1.Handle, IconHandle);
end;
```

And for example pass the 0 image index to the VirtualTreeView.

```
procedure TForm10.VirtualStringTree1GetImageIndex(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex;
  var Ghosted: Boolean; var ImageIndex: Integer);
begin
  ImageIndex := 0;
end;
```

Comment: IconClass is a very bad name for an object reference. It's not a class. I'd call it `Icon`. To make it even simpler I'd just write `ImageList_AddIcon(ImageList1.Handle, IconHandle)` and avoid using a `TIcon` altogether.

Comment: @David - I've edited the answer by your suggestions. Thanks. About the IconClass, I know it's a bad name; it's the instance not a class.